# Database rollback error in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, database

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pinnacle_mage476
>     .mgw2_store_website' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT mgw2_store_website.
>     * FROM mgw2_store_website

I am facing this issue. Anyone help fix this
Thanks

Comment: Did you use any custom module which has mgw2_store_website table? This table is missing in your database. Create this table will fix your problem

Comment: Yes @SohelRana is right but it seems the that pinnacle_mage476 table is missing.

Comment: If I do rollback from phpMyadmin getting Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 58)
SQL query:

-- -- Dumping data for table `mgw2_inventory_stock_1` -- LOCK TABLES `mgw2_inventory_stock_1` WRITE

MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'pinnacle_mage476.mgw2_inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist